# MongoDB cannot connect once in Azure - asp core 3.1 - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

My application runs just fine with MongoDB string when I run it locally, it can connect to the remote mongoDB database, to add/retrieve data just fine.

```
"MyDatabaseSettings": {
"ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://admin:<PWD>@cluster0-7yxfg.mongodb.net/<DBNAME>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&connect=replicaSet"},
```

However, as soon as I publish to Azure, I get a connection error as show below.
If I comment out the access to MongoDB in the code then the whole app works fine on Azure too. It really seems to be because of the access to MongoDB. Do I need to declare some specific IP or do more MongoDB setup in Azure? I was under the impression that the string of connection would do the trick and that it would just work once deployed in Azure too...

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-08-30T20:31:47.3607137Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-01-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-01-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-08-30T20:31:47.4624960Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-02-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-02-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-08-30T20:31:47.4406769Z" }] }.
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream. at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-08-30T20:31:47.3607137Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-01-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-01-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream. at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-08-30T20:31:47.4624960Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-02-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-02-7yxfg.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream. at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-08-30T20:31:47.4406769Z" }] }.
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster+WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl.UsingImplicitSession(Func<IClientSessionHandle, TResult> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl.FindSync(FilterDefinition filter, FindOptions<TDocument, TProjection> options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent<TDocument, TProjection>.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList(IAsyncCursorSource source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Traveller.Classes.TSPUtilsDb.TSPUtilsDb_GetAtlas(DocumentService iDocService, TSPAtlas iAtlas, string iDbName, string iCollectionName) in TSPUtils.cs
Traveller.Controllers.DefinitionController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext iContext) in DefinitionController.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ControllerActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details

Comment: What happens in mongo shell when you use this URI?

Comment: Is the Azure instance allowed by the Atlas whitelist?

Comment: @Joe Thx actually I tough I did, as an IP was whitelisted for Azure, but I tried to change it to 0.0.0.0/0 instead to open it up and it now works, so I guess it was the wrong IP originally. Will find the right one to add instead now.